# print statement in test function changes outcome of test

Tags: python

Function being tested:

```
def first_ball_contacts(self, timestep):
    """Returns the time and all touching ballpairs (ball_1, ball_2) at the time of the first ball-ball collision within the timestep"""

    first_ball_contacts = {'time': timestep, 'collidors': []} # collidors will be Ball

    for ball_1, ball_2 in itertools.combinations(self.balls, 2):

        t = self.collision_time(ball_1, ball_2, timestep)
        if t!=None:
            if t < first_ball_contacts['time']:

                first_ball_contacts['time'] = t
                first_ball_contacts['collidors'] = [(ball_1, ball_2)]

            elif t == first_ball_contacts['time']:

                first_ball_contacts['collidors'].append((ball_1, ball_2))

    return first_ball_contacts
```

Test function:

```
def test_first_ball_contacts_2_balls(self):

    board = Board(width = 100, height = 100, sps = 1) # Same thing with one line changed
    ball_1 = board.add_ball(x = 45, y = 50, r = 5, vx = 2, vy = 0, m = 1)
    ball_2 = board.add_ball(x = 55, y = 50, r = 5, vx = -2, vy = 0, m = 1)

    contacts = board.first_ball_contacts(1)

    print("FROM "+str(contacts))

    self.assertEqual(contacts['time'], 0)
    self.assertEqual(contacts['collidors'], [(ball_1, ball_2)])
```

When I run this test, it is successful:

```
(balls) Sahands-MBP:src sahandzarrinkoub$ python test_boardmodel.py
.......FROM {'time': 0.0, 'collidors': [(<model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x105786e10>, <model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x105786e48>)]}
..........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 17 tests in 0.004s

OK
```

But when I remove the print statement (or if I change it to something else, for example if I change it to `print(str(contacts))`), the test fails:

```
.......F.........
======================================================================
FAIL: test_first_ball_contacts_2_balls (__main__.BoardModelMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_boardmodel.py", line 282, in test_first_ball_contacts_2_balls
    self.assertEqual(contacts['collidors'], [(ball_1, ball_2)])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [(<mo[28 chars]t 0x10c56ae10>, <model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56add8>)] != [(<mo[28 chars]t 0x10c56add8>, <model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56ae10>)]

First differing element 0:
(<mod[26 chars]at 0x10c56ae10>, <model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56add8>)
(<mod[26 chars]at 0x10c56add8>, <model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56ae10>)

- [(<model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56ae10>,
?                                            ^^^

+ [(<model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56add8>,
?                                            ^^^

-   <model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56add8>)]
?                                            ^^^

+   <model.boardmodel.Ball object at 0x10c56ae10>)]
?                                            ^^^
```

Also, if I comment out the `print` statement, the test is successful. This is very strange behaviour that I would like to understand. How can a `print`-statement have any effect on the contests of the dictionary it's printing? Especially if the `print` statement is commented out!

EDIT: It seems like it didn't still succeed after I commented the `print` statement out. However, it stills fails if I remove it entirely. So the same questions remains: Why does this print statement change the outcome of the test?

Also, don't get hung up on why I've written `"FROM "` inside the print. I discovered this strange behaviour by accident and would like to have it explained.